# Metadata gathering Script for Metaplex using React, need help

Tags: metaplex, metadata, query

I've been trying to build a simple script that pulls the metadata from Metaplex NFTs using the React code below:

```
import { Metaplex } from "@metaplex-foundation/js";
import { Connection, clusterApiUrl } from "@solana/web3.js";

const connection = new Connection(clusterApiUrl("mainnet-beta"));
const metaplex = new Metaplex(connection);
const nft = await metaplex.nfts().findByMint({ mintAddress }).run();

async function App() {
  const [nftA, nftB] = await Metaplex(nftA.nfts(),
  nftA.findAllByMintList({ mints: ["mintA", "mintB"] }),
  nftB.run());
   
  resolve.fallback: { "path": false };

  console.log();
}

export default App;
```

The issue I've been running into is this error: **Line 25:18:  Parsing error: Missing semicolon. (25:18)**

Any ideas on this one? A simple console log is what I'm looking for as I just need the info.

Answer (score 1):

How about?

```
    const _f = async () => {
      const metaplex = new Metaplex(connection);
      const nftList = await metaplex.nfts().findAllByMintList([new PublicKey(`........Some NFT Address...........`)]);
      const nftsToLoad = nftList.filter((nft, index) => {
        return (nft != null && nft.metadataTask.isPending());
      });
      const promises = nftsToLoad.map((nft) => nft?.metadataTask.run());
      await Promise.all(promises);

      nftsToLoad.map((nft) => {
        console.log('metadata', nft?.metadata);
      });
    };
    _f();
```

Comment: still getting the error :/ its says it's in this section ```sync function App(nftA,nftB) {
  const [nftA, nftB] = await metaplex
    nftA.nfts()
    .findAllByMintList({ mints: ["mintA", "mintB"] })
    nftB.run()
    
    resolve.fallback: = { "path": false };```

Comment: I don't know Javascript well, I think `resolve.fallback: = {"path": false};` invalid sentance.
Do you mean `resolve.fallback = {...resolve.fallback, path: false};` ?

Comment: I update answer.